# @inject WebServiceContext

Tags: jax-ws, java-ee-6, cdi

Since the WebServiceContext is a resource, I tried to inject it into an `SLSB` webservice by writing a producer field and then using `@inject`.
That didn't work. It seems like the `WebServiceContext` is related to the `ThreadLocal` however the instance containning the producer field will not access that.

Is there someone who tried that?

Please note, that using `@Resource` (without CDI) everything works. Also, by putting the producer field inside my webservice the @`inject` works (of course that couldn't be the solution )

Answer (score 0):

There was talk about unifying that in EE7, but it isn't going to happen. For now you'll have to do it the old way.